# iOS In App subscription - detecting the opt-in marketing incentive extension

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

How do you detect that the purchaser of an In App auto-renewable subscription has selected to provide marketing data so that you can give them a 7 or 30 day extension of the subscription time period?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that since Apple is responsible for automatic renewals, the onus is on Apple to grant your customers who opt in an extension when you answer "Yes" to the question "Offer a marketing opt-in incentive?" in iTunes Connect.

There's no way to programmatically detect an opt-in.

Comment: Actually, the App itself needs to determine the subscription length so this can't be correct.  There must be a way of seeing the time period.

Comment: Despite what the documentation says about determining the subscription length, you *do* get an expiration date (that reflects user opt-ins) when you verify the receipt on the server. I use that date to determine expirations.

Comment: From where the email, zip code etc to be sent to server? Does the app needs to show any view to accept such information? Where should the info needs to be sent?

Comment: User info isn't sent to the server, but rather it's exposed in iTunes Connect. You don't need to display a view or anything; Apple provides the information automatically, straight from a user's iTunes account profile.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke to Apple directly (August 19th 2012) and they informed me that the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5) about determining the length of auto-renewing subscriptions is wrong and will be updated.

Checking the expires_date is the correct way to determine the subscription expiration.  That date will be adjusted depending on whether the user chooses the opt-in marketing incentive and also whether they've been offered a free trial (for Newsstand apps) or not.  It's critical to pay attention to the expires_date and not just assume durations based on the product ID.

That information will also be included on restored transactions.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here. To clarify:

- You can offer a free/extended subscription period to users who provide marketing information to you
- This marketing information is available for review in iTunes Connect
- You set up the incentive subscription **in iTunes Connect when you create the subscription product**

So when you go into iTunes Connect and create a new auto-renewable subscription in the in app purchase section there's a check box labelled 'Offer a marketing incentive?'. If you check 'Yes' you'll be able to select the length of incentive you'd like to offer, which ranges from seven days to one year.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Apple's procedure for [Verifying Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5)* to discover the `expires_date`.  Then provide the user access to your service up until the expiration date.  If you want to determine if they opted in, you could try comparing the `purchase_date` to the `expires_date` to determine the length of the subscription.  If it's longer than the period of your product, they probably opted in.

Be aware that `purchase_date` may not be the actual date the product was purchased if this transaction was `restored`. However, it appears that `original_purchase_date` is the date the user first initiated any subscription with you. Even if the subscription has renewed multiple times, or lapsed and restarted.

*
See here for a brief [Summary of the Receipt Verification Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8017962/241138).

Answer (score 0):

The docs state:
"The expiration date of the subscription receipt, expressed as the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. This key is not included on restored transactions."

So if you restore the transactions you do not get this value. What to do in that case?