# Notification of cancellation of auto-renewal for an in-app purchase

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

I am working on an iPhone app and I want to implement the new model of auto-renewal for in-app purchases. I am able to successfully implement transactions and can even get subscribed to the app, but what if the user cancels the auto renewal subscription?

How will I be able to know that it has been cancelled, and so not continue to allow access (once expired)?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the expiration date of a user's subscription by sending a receipt verification to Apple's servers.  Check out figure 1-3 on the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH100-SW1).

Basically the steps are:

1. On the device, get a transaction receipt for an in-app-purchase.  Either one you've saved during a transaction or by calling `[SKPaymentQueue restoreCompletedTransactions]`.
2. Send that receipt to your server.  (This is preferred over trying to do a receipt verification with Apple's servers directly from the app, since that would require you to store your shared secret on the device.)
3. Send the receipt to Apple's servers from your server, and in the response look for a key named `expires_date` (expressed in **milli** seconds since Jan 1, 1970 GMT).

I used this guide to help me on the server side: [Verifying Apple App Store Receipts For In App Purchases With PHP and cURL](http://phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl).

There is no way to determine if the user has auto-renewal turned on or off.  Apple doesn't give you access to this information.  The only way is to wait until the expiration date passes without a renewal.

Comment: Hey andrew , it is possible to subscribe from iTunes account1 and then Change the iTunes Account to Account2 , and App Should  go on with new  iTunes Account i.e. Account2. The App should not asked for  purchases from iTunes Account 2. How should I Manage.?  I am using Auto-Renewal Subscription.

Answer (score 2):

if the receipt status is `21006` and there is a key named `cancellation_date`, then it's a cancellation, you can find the new expiration date in that key but it's a formatted date, if you need a better value to parse check for `receipt['latest_expired_receipt_info']['cancellation_date_ms']` same as `expires_date`

Comment: I didn't got receipt['latest_expired_receipt_info']. is it getting anymore?

Comment: i am not getting any of the mentioned keys.

Comment: Only returned for iOS 6-style transaction receipts for auto-renewable subscriptions ([Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status))