# auto renewable subscription, Cancel notification?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store, auto-renewable

I'm working with IAP Auto-Renewable Subscription, my question is if a user cancels the subscription then how will my server be notified.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notification of cancellation of auto-renewal for an in-app purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302517/notification-of-cancellation-of-auto-renewal-for-an-in-app-purchase)

Answer (score 0):

if the receipt status is 21006 and there is a key named `cancellation_date`, then it's a cancellation, you can find the new expiration date in that key but it's a formatted date, if you need a better value to parse check for `receipt['latest_expired_receipt_info']['cancellation_date_ms']` same as `expires_date`

There is more info here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html