# What is the format of the cancellation_date field in Apple IAP receipt / status notifications

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, receipt-validation

The Apple documentation for server to server notifications does not specify what data format will come in the cancellation_date field. I'm trying to setup some unit tests for my notification handler but I'm not sure what data to put in my mock response.

I would assume that it is milliseconds since epoch but where other fields are noted in the documentation as being that, the cancellation_date field just reads, "The time and date that a transaction was cancelled by Apple customer support."

Can anyone confirm the date format that is in the cancellation_date field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did find this today:

> if the receipt status is 21006 and there is a key named
>   cancellation_date, then it’s a cancellation, you can find the new
>   expiration date in that key but it’s a formatted date, if you need a
>   better value to parse check for
>   receipt['latest_expired_receipt_info']['cancellation_date_ms'] same as
>   expires_date

[Notification of cancellation of auto-renewal for an in-app purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302517/notification-of-cancellation-of-auto-renewal-for-an-in-app-purchase)

I've also now confirmed this in production. There's a `cancellation_date_ms` property of `latest_expired_receipt_info` and also in the root of the notification itself. `cancellation_date` is a formatted date string.

Here's a partial production notification:

`{
    "environment": "PROD",
    "auto_renew_status": "false",
    "latest_expired_receipt_info": {
        "original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-25 11:59:25 America/Los_Angeles",
        "cancellation_date_ms": "1517150504000",
        "cancellation_reason": "0",
        "original_purchase_date_ms": "1516910365000",
        "expires_date_formatted": "2019-01-25 19:59:23 Etc/GMT",
        "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
        "purchase_date_ms": "1516910363000",
        "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2019-01-25 11:59:23 America/Los_Angeles",
        "is_trial_period": "false",
        "expires_date": "1548446363000",
        "cancellation_date": "2018-01-28 14:41:44 Etc/GMT",
        "purchase_date": "2018-01-25 19:59:23 Etc/GMT",
        "cancellation_date_pst": "2018-01-28 06:41:44 America/Los_Angeles",
        "purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-25 11:59:23 America/Los_Angeles",
        "original_purchase_date": "2018-01-25 19:59:25 Etc/GMT"
    },
    "cancellation_date_ms": "1517150504000"
}`

Comment: Thanks. I have not found an answer to this yet and have not been able to capture it in the real world yet. This seems like good info and I will have to check my code to see if I'm handling things as you have described.

Comment: I tweaked our server and have now received the "CANCEL" notification properly. See updated answer.

Comment: any reason why auto_renew_status is outside of your latest info? the document says that field should be inside the receipt info.

Comment: According to [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/status): The value for status is 0 if the receipt is valid, or a status code if there is an error. The status code reflects the status of the app receipt as a whole. For example, if you send a valid app receipt that contains an expired subscription, the response is 0 because the receipt is valid.